# How to create a slack message shortcut, that shows up only in messages from a specific channel?

Tags: slack, shortcut

I'm creating a simple slack app that adds a shortcut message, but this shortcut is only meant to be used in messages from a certain channel.
It is possible to show the shortcut only in the specific channel?

Regards
Luis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to create a "Message Shortcut" only for a specific channel.
 The best possible option you have is to update the application such that it filters invocation from other channels.

Comment: Actually, my app already does that, but the shortcut shows up in all the channels even though it only makes sense in one of them. Thank you very much, Suyash.

Comment: @Luis you can consider adding button to your message instead of a shotcut. Then you can introduce interactivity per message, not per whole workspace.